# Custom field not updating via functions upon publishing

Tags: functions, pages

I've created the code so that on publish of the page, the custom field 'bookinfo' in the page is automatically generated but its not doing anything

Below is my code in in `functions.php`:-

```
<?php
if (is_page()){  

function generate_page_html( $page_id ) {

$title=get_the_title();
$link=get_the_permalink();
$booktxt='new book'.$title.'at'.$link.'grab quickly';    

update_page_meta( $page_id, 'bookinfo', $booktxt); 
}

add_action( 'save_page', 'generate_page_html' );
}
?>
```

P.S i am using advanced custom fields to create the custom field where the rule is to display the field group of posttype is page

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems that I can see that cause your code to fail.

The first is that you're using update_page_meta, which does not exist. Use `update_post_meta` instead.

The second is that you're using the action `save_page`, which also does not exist. Use [`save_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post), `save_post` is an action triggered whenever a post or page is created or updated, so it is appropriate to use in your case.

For an overview of actions that you can use, see [Action Reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference)

Comment: i made the changes as u said but the fields don't get updated even then

Comment: the whole code is in functions.php ..i want it to be applied when i update or publish a page so the custom field of the page i.e 'bookinfo' has the $booktxt thats generated

Comment: i am using advanced custom fields to create the custom field where the rule is to display the field group of posttype is page

Comment: is_page() probably isn't evaluating to true then